# how to retrieve some field from ldap in spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, ldap

i m new to spring.  i want to retrieve some field of user details  from ldap and display on the jsp page. how can i retrieve this filed from ldap on page load?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="ldap://url:389" />
        <property name="base" value="dc" />
        <property name="userName" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
        <property name="password" value="secret" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapContact"
        class="org.LDAPContactDAO">
        <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It give me following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContact' defined in class path resource [springldap.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ldapTemplate' while setting bean property 'ldapTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapTemplate' defined in class path resource [springldap.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'contextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextSource' defined in class path resource [springldap.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'userName' of bean class [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: Bean property 'userName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.SpringFrameworkLDAPClient.main(SpringFrameworkLDAPClient.java:20)
```

I have write down some class file

```
package org;
public class ContactDTO {

    private String displayName;
    // lastName = Person.sn
    private String firstName;
    private String company;
    private String department;

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }


    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer contactDTOStr = new StringBuffer("Person=[");

        contactDTOStr.append(" firstName = " + firstName);
        contactDTOStr.append(" ]");
        return contactDTOStr.toString();
    }
}
```

//interface ContactDAO

```
package org;
import java.util.List;

public interface ContactDAO {

    public List getAllContactNames();

    /*public List getContactDetails(String commonName);*/

}
```

// LDAPContactDAO

```
package org;
import java.util.List;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;


public class LDAPContactDAO implements ContactDAO{

    @Override
    public List getAllContactNames() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }




    /*public List getContactDetails(String objectclass){
        AndFilter andFilter = new AndFilter();
        andFilter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectClass",objectclass));
        System.out.println("LDAP Query " + andFilter.encode());
        return ldapTemplate.search("", andFilter.encode(),new ContactAttributeMapper());

    }*/
}



package org;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

public class SpringFrameworkLDAPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/SpringLDAPClient/src/com/javaworld/sample/springldap.xml");
        //System.out.println(resource.toString());
        try {
            Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("springldap.xml");
            BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
            System.out.println(factory.toString() + "\n");

            ContactDAO ldapContact = (LDAPContactDAO)factory.getBean("ldapContact");    

            /*List contactList = ldapContact.getContactDetails("30662");*/
            //List contactList =ldapContact.getAllContactNames();
            //System.out.println(contactList.size());
            /*int count = 0;
            for( int i = 0 ; i < contactList.size(); i++){
                System.out.print("Email: " + ((ContactDTO) contactList.get(i)).getMail() + "  ");
                System.out.println("SAP: " + ((ContactDTO) contactList.get(i)).getSap());
                count++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + count);
 */
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured " + e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

But i am not able display this user details on jsp page? please any body know about this reply

Answer (score 1):

The important part of the error message is:

```
Error creating bean with name 'contextSource'
    defined in class path resource [springldap.xml]: 
Error setting property values;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'userName'
    of bean class [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource]: 
Bean property 'userName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I don't know wich version of Spring LDAP You're using, but `userName` seems to be deprecated in version 1.2 and completely removed in version 1.3 - try `userDn` instead, and see reference section on [DirContext Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/configuration.html#dir-context-authentication)

---

And on how to get user details from LDAP try the reference: [User Authentication using Spring LDAP](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/user-authentication.html)

Or even better: use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) with [LDAP Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html).

Comment: thanks for this information. i have change spring-ldap 1.1 to 1.3 version. basically i want to retrive user details from ldap and dispaly on jsp page. do you have some example so that i will better understand it?

Comment: Any body have any idea of  how to retrieve  user details from ldap using ldap template?